# Magento2 NGINX run external PHP scripts

Tags: nginx, magento2

Magento2 site setup on AWS with NGINX. Site working fine.
I am trying to allow PHP scripts to run if they are in a specific folder, but they always 404.

I have placed the following inside my nginx config file, and restarted nginx:

```
 location /custom_tests/ {
    location ~* \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
            fastcgi_buffers 1024 4k;

            fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
            fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
    }
 }
```

I am trying to access scripts that are in sub directories of the 'custom_tests' folder, but i have also added an index.php in the 'custom_tests' folder itself. All i get is 404 not found.

I have the above NGINX entry just above the following block in the config file:

```
# PHP entry point for main application
 location ~ (index|get|static|report|404|503|health_check)\.php$ {
```

Comment: Your "PHP entry point for main application" will always match `index.php`. Try: `location ^~ /custom_tests/`

Comment: Still 404. So modified the block start to:
location ^~/custom_tests/ {
        location ~* \.php$ {........